# Trouble finding solution to "variable might not have been initialized" error

Tags: java

My java program takes input from the user on the command line. The user has a choice: he may either specify a plain-text file as input with the -inputfile option, or he may leave this option unspecified, in which case the program takes input from System.in. (I've observed this behavior in some programs that come pre-installed with my Ubuntu distro, so I infer that it is  acceptable practice.)

So I make a `BufferedReader` (`inBR`)that reads from the file, if provided, and a `Scanner` (`inScanner`) that reads from `System.in` otherwise. Only one of these objects is actually instantiated, the other is left as null. Later on, when the program reads a line from input, I have the following code:

```
String line;
if (inBR != null) {
    line = inBR.readLine(); (1)
} else {
    line = inScanner.nextLine(); (2)
}
```

Which gives me the compile time errors `variable inBR might not have been initialized` and `variable inScanner might not have been initialized` at lines (1) and (2), respectively.

What is the acceptable solution here? I've considered, "initialize the variable that's supposed to be null as an Object to shut up the compiler." But this is just a hack; surely there's a better way.

Also, why isn't this a runtime exception, as a `NullPointerException`?

EDIT: inScanner.readLine() => inScanner.nextLine()

Comment: I think you need to show us more code, like maybe where you initialize your inBR and inScanner

Comment: Initialize them to null when you declare them.

Comment: It's not a runtime exception because it didn't occur at run time; it occurred at compile time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declaring them this way would avoid the compilation error :

```
BufferedReader inBR = null;
Scanner inScanner = null;
```

Of course you still have to give them actual values before accessing them, or you'll get `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Wow I'm stupid. Okay. Thanks. I saw other SO answers like this and assumed they didn't work in my case, for some reason. "Initialized" means the pointer to the object is created, even if that pointer points to null?

Comment: @Mickeysofine It's called a reference in Java (not a pointer), but yes, it means the reference is initialized, and it can be initialized to null.

Answer (score 1):

In java all variables that are used must be initialized at some point.

```
public void example(){
  String name;

  if(name == null) return null;

}
```

In the above example the variable name has not been initialized.  There are several ways to solve this problem:

```
public void example1(){
  String name = null;

  if(name == null) return null;
}
```

This would solve the problem.

This would also solve the problem

```
public void exapmle2(){
  String name = "";

  if(name == null) return null;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the condition whether or not a file is provided. For example, if a file is provided, create the buffered reader and set line immediately. Otherwise, create a scanner and set the line.